# Views Panels exposed filter in configuration AND exposed to the user

Tags: views, panels

I couldn't find an answer.
Is possible to make a views pane have a pre configured filter (using the views exposed filter and configuring using the panels) AND show the exposed filter to the users?

I want to have a views that a admin can place using the panels configuration, and set what filters they want for that views.
But, I also want to allow the user to change this filters when he sees the page.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: exposed forms may be available as blocks

Comment: I got the message:Placeholder for empty or inaccessible "Exposed form: produtos-panel_pane_4" from panels.
If I unset in the views "Allow settings" the "Use exposed widgets form as pane configuration" checkbox the form shows correctly. =P

Comment: exposed filter must have default value

Comment: Thanks for the ideia =D.
I tried with a default value on a simple checkbox filter (the only filter in use). The block works as long as the pane isn't configured to expose the configuration to panels. When I save, the panels don't show the form anymore and in the edit page shows the:"**Placeholder for empty or inaccessible "Exposed form: produtos-panel_pane_5"**" message. =P

Comment: I wonder if you ever got this figured out?

Comment: If I remember correctly (it was more than a year ago), I ended up using js to get the admin inputs from the url (GET parameteres), and force a ajax reload on the views. This allowed the admin to chose a pre-set of form inputs, but still allowed the end user to change them. My case was mostly links to a product views with categories and checkboxes options.